# Opening a Link to Safari Using a Button Swift App Crashing?

Tags: ios, swift, unrecognized-selector

I am creating an app that acts like my school website. I added a button that I want to link to their original website using this code.

```
import UIKit

class RearTableVC: UITableViewController {

    @IBAction func portal(sender: AnyObject) {
        let websiteAddress = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(websiteAddress!)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

After running the app and clicking the button the app crashes leaving the error.

```
2015-11-29 11:10:45.554 FAQ[16888:2329672] -[FAQ.RearTableVC Button:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd0e857c6c0
2015-11-29 11:10:45.560 FAQ[16888:2329672] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FAQ.RearTableVC Button:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd0e857c6c0'
```

I am fairly new at programming using Swift so I am looking for all the help I can get.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add the `Button:` function to handle the button event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you renamed your `Button` function to `portal` after you wired up the button.

To correct this, in the Storyboard, <kbd>Control</kbd>-click on your button and then remove the event for *Touch Up Inside* by clicking on the little *x*.

[image]

Then drag from the circle next to *Touch Up Inside* to your `portal` function.

[image]

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and I am still getting the crash error.

Comment: Is it the exact same error, or a different one?  Does is still say `-[FAQ.RearTableVC Button:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` when you press the button?

Comment: Yes it does still say -[FAQ.RearTableVC Button:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: What do you see now if you control-click on your button in the Storyboard?  Does it look like my top picture?

Comment: Touch up inside should say portal and only portal.  If it is still linked to Button, click the x next to the View Controller name.

Comment: I got it now thanks for the help so much! It was very appreciated and I will be posting other questions regarding how to code more often. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, click the checkmark next to it to turn it green.  Thanks.